# Date range tree implementation in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, tree

I'm looking for a **fast** date range tree implementation in python.

This is what I want to be able to do (pseudocode):

```
start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)
end = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=10)

# assignment
rangetree[start:end] = data

# query
print(rangetree[datetime.datetime.now()])
```

I have found interval tree implementations in Python (https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/ncls) but nothing that uses datetime/date objects for indexing in the tree.

Comment: you can get the "total seconds since" route which is just a mediocre big integer for any reasonable date in/of the last 200/next 200 years. numpy and pandas are quite good with tables. asking for 3rd party libs is declared offtopic here and a reason to close requests.

Comment: We need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.